# Pagina PHP dentro de um DIV após submit

Tags: php, html

Tenho um formulário aonde o usuário digita qual equipamento ele deseja consultar e
**DEPOIS** de clicar em confirmar, **preciso que os campos com as informações** apareçam. Esses campos estão em outro arquivo PHP que fará os selects baseado no dado selecionado no formulário. Utilizar hidden não atende ao que eu estou precisando

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">      
        <label style="margin-top: 5px;">
            <span style="margin-right: 18px;">Equipamento:</span>
            <input type="text" name="equipamento" id="equipamento" size="12" style="margin-top: 5px;" autofocus required>
        </label>
        <input style="margin-left: 20px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirmar">
</form>
    <br>
        <div> <?php require_once("test.php"); ?> </div>
```

Os dados precisam aparecer dentro da DIV acima.

Comment: Você pode usar Ajax e fazer a requisição para esse arquivo php. Após o retorno você popula a sua div com as informações que você precisa.

Comment: Você sabe me dizer como da pra fazer isto?

Comment: Acredito que entendi sua ideia, porém a lógica para sua necessidade pode ser melhor... ao invés de você inputar via include um arquivo após a ação no formulário, vc pode apenas fazer um innerHtml() ou um append, e usar estes métodos(javascript) para inputar trexos de código e dar sequencia na sua lógica. Para isso, voce usa o serialize para enviar o formulario via ajax e no retorno vc verifica se foi ok seu submit e carrega o retorno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem usar Ajax, você pode fazer um POST para a mesma página e condicionar a exibição da `div` ao recebimento do valor do formulário.

No *include* você envia o valor recebido via GET para a página `test.php`. Assim, após submeter o formulário, a página `test.php` inclusa na `div` irá retornar com o HTML baseado no parâmetro enviado via GET.

Ficaria assim:

```
<form method="post">      
  <label style="margin-top: 5px;">
      <span style="margin-right: 18px;">Equipamento:</span>
      <input type="text" name="equipamento" id="equipamento" size="12" style="margin-top: 5px;" autofocus required>
  </label>
  <input style="margin-left: 20px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirmar">
</form>
<br>
<?php
// só irá mostrar a div se houver valor
// enviado pelo formulário
$equipamento = $_POST['equipamento'];
if(!empty($equipamento)){
?>
<div>
   <?php
   $_GET['equipamento'] = $equipamento;
   require_once("test.php");
   ?>
</div> 
<?php
}
?>
```

Página `test.php`:

```
<?php
$equipamento = $_GET['equipamento'];
if(!empty($equipamento)){
   // faz alguma coisa com a variável $equipamento
   // que é a string enviada pelo formulário
}
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, amanhã eu vou poder realizar o teste e confirmo se funcionou. Até então parece que é exatamente o que eu preciso.

Comment: Blz... pelo menos aqui eu testo tudo antes de postar, e funfa tranquilo. Abs!

Comment: Testei e funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.